# C arrays and pointers, what happens when I give an array new address?

Tags: c

So I have two character arrays:

```
char results[80];
char *copy = "blah";
```

What happens when I say??:

```
results = copy;
```

Comment: Nothing happens. It won't compile. You cannot "give an array new address" in C.

Answer (score 4):

This is a constraint violation, as you can't use the `=` operator to reassign an array. As a result, if you bothered to [*try* this simple experiment](http://ideone.com/Pe7DJc)<sup>(code below)</sup>, you'd have noticed you'll get an error message that looks something like this:

```
prog.c:6:13: error: assignment to expression with array type
```

---

```
int main(void) {
    char results[80];
    char *copy = "blah";
    results = copy;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get an error.

```
test.c:8:13: error: array type 'char [80]' is not assignable
    results = copy;
    ~~~~~~~ ^
```

The [C FAQ covers this a bit](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/arrayassign.html). The relevant bit of the ISO standard is 6.3.2.1.

> A modifiable lvalue is an lvalue that ***does not have array type***, does not have an incomplete type, does not have a const-qualified type, and if it is a structure or union, does not have any member (including, recursively, any member or element of all contained aggregates or unions) with a const-qualified type.

The [Rationale](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf) explains why.

> The role of array objects has been a classic source of confusion in C, in large part because of the numerous contexts in which an array reference is converted to a pointer to its first element. While this conversion neatly handles the semantics of subscripting, the fact that a[i] is a
>   modifiable lvalue while a is not has puzzled many students of the language. A more precise description was incorporated in C89 in the hope of combatting this confusion.

Aaaand... yeah, that really isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Let me simplify the program to:

char a[] = "Sunstroke";
char *b = a;

Assume that the address of a is 100, then in memory, it looks like this (illustrating only the size of pointer and endian-ness etc. may vary):

```
[S] [u] [n] [s] [t] [r] [o] [k] [e] [\0]         ...       [0] [0] [0] [100]
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109                           200
 ^                                                                 ^
 |                                                                 |
 a                                                                 b
```

As long as the life cycle of the array, a will always be the same place, you can't modify it.

b, on the other hand, is a pointer that contains the address of the array, you can modify the value of b to point to other places.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strcpy()` function.Like,

```
char results[80];
char *copy = "blah";

strcpy( results, copy );
printf("%s\n",results);
```